# Exporting an FFDF without NA values

Tags: r

I need to share data sets that I've imported into R as ffdf objects.  **My aim is to easily be able to export my ffdf datasets into CSV format, without having to worry about NA values which just inflate the size of the output file.**

If I were working with a simple dataframe, I would use the following syntax:

```
write.csv(df, "C:/path/data.csv", row.names=FALSE, na="")
```

But the write.csv.ffdf function doesn't seem to take "na" as an argument.  Can anyone tell me the correct syntax so that I don't have to do post processing on the output file to take away the NA values?

Comment: How about just using `write.table` with the desired arguments?  BTW, as "ffdf" is not a base object type, you should post the package you're using which supports this type.

Comment: My apologies.  The ff package supports this type of data frame.

Comment: I don't see anything in the `write.table.ffdf` documentation which precludes assigning an `na` value, so perhaps you should call `write.table` and specify the `FUN` value.  In the meantime, try extracting a small but representative sample of your `ffdf` object to a local dataframe and seeing what happens when you try to use `write.csv` with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are making inaccurate characterization of the behavior of `write.csv.ffdf`.

```
require(ff)  
# What follows is a minor modification of the first example in the `write.* help page.

> x <- data.frame(log=rep(c(FALSE, TRUE), length.out=26), int=c(NA, 2:26), 
                  dbl=c(1:25,NA) + 0.1, fac=factor(c(letters[2:26], NA)),
                  ord=c(NA, ordered(LETTERS[2:26])), dct=Sys.time()+1:26, 
                  dat=seq(as.Date("1910/1/1"), length.out=26, by=1))
>  ffx <- as.ffdf(x)
> write.csv(ffx, na="")
"","log","int","dbl","fac","ord","dct","dat"
"1",FALSE,,1.1,"b",,2012-12-18 12:18:23,1910-01-01
"2",TRUE,2,2.1,"c",1,2012-12-18 12:18:24,1910-01-02
"3",FALSE,3,3.1,"d",2,2012-12-18 12:18:25,1910-01-03
"4",TRUE,4,4.1,"e",3,2012-12-18 12:18:26,1910-01-04
"5",FALSE,5,5.1,"f",4,2012-12-18 12:18:27,1910-01-05
"6",TRUE,6,6.1,"g",5,2012-12-18 12:18:28,1910-01-06
"7",FALSE,7,7.1,"h",6,2012-12-18 12:18:29,1910-01-07
"8",TRUE,8,8.1,"i",7,2012-12-18 12:18:30,1910-01-08
"9",FALSE,9,9.1,"j",8,2012-12-18 12:18:31,1910-01-09
"10",TRUE,10,10.1,"k",9,2012-12-18 12:18:32,1910-01-10
"11",FALSE,11,11.1,"l",10,2012-12-18 12:18:33,1910-01-11
"12",TRUE,12,12.1,"m",11,2012-12-18 12:18:34,1910-01-12
"13",FALSE,13,13.1,"n",12,2012-12-18 12:18:35,1910-01-13
"14",TRUE,14,14.1,"o",13,2012-12-18 12:18:36,1910-01-14
"15",FALSE,15,15.1,"p",14,2012-12-18 12:18:37,1910-01-15
"16",TRUE,16,16.1,"q",15,2012-12-18 12:18:38,1910-01-16
"17",FALSE,17,17.1,"r",16,2012-12-18 12:18:39,1910-01-17
"18",TRUE,18,18.1,"s",17,2012-12-18 12:18:40,1910-01-18
"19",FALSE,19,19.1,"t",18,2012-12-18 12:18:41,1910-01-19
"20",TRUE,20,20.1,"u",19,2012-12-18 12:18:42,1910-01-20
"21",FALSE,21,21.1,"v",20,2012-12-18 12:18:43,1910-01-21
"22",TRUE,22,22.1,"w",21,2012-12-18 12:18:44,1910-01-22
"23",FALSE,23,23.1,"x",22,2012-12-18 12:18:45,1910-01-23
"24",TRUE,24,24.1,"y",23,2012-12-18 12:18:46,1910-01-24
"25",FALSE,25,25.1,"z",24,2012-12-18 12:18:47,1910-01-25
"26",TRUE,26,,,25,2012-12-18 12:18:48,1910-01-26
```

If your goal is minimizing the RAM footprint during write operations, then first look at:

```
getOption("ffbatchbytes")
```

Comment: Thank you Carl and DWin.  I didn't realize that you can simply use write.csv/table with an ffdf object and still operate well within your computer's resources :)

Comment: I just practised using write.csv on a really big ffdf that I have, and it took up more than a couple of gigabytes of RAM in the process.

I'm still wondering how to write an ffdf to csv, with no NA values, but while conserving RAM usage.

Comment: @inkhorn: Using `write.csv` on an ffdf object is really using `write.csv.ffdf`. The interpreter gets dispatched to that function. You have not told us why you think it is the NA's that are occupying space, so perhaps that theory will prove false on testing as well? (I would imagine that R will use as much RAM as it can get.)

Comment: Note: the write.csv.ffdf function accepts an argument `BATCHBYTES` which defaults to: `getOption("ffbatchbytes")`, but can be changed to suit the user's needs.

Answer (score 0):

`write.csv.ffdf` does not have an `na` parameter, but `write.table.ffdf` passes the `na` parameter onto the `write.table1` function that it wraps.
Just use `sep=","` as well and you are good to go.

This will work even for large ff variables.